# Saving two models to sync into pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a request controller that has two Model to be `save` for me able to sync this into my pivot table. I still don't have idea how I'm gonna sync one of the two Models in my Controller. I have `Documents` and `Approves` M:M relationship with a pivot table `approve_document`

Model

Document:

```
public function approves()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Document', 'approve_document');
}
```

Approve:

```
public function pendingDocuments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Document', 'approve_document');
}
```

Controller:

```
$document = new Document();
$approve = new Approve();
                                //Request in the form
$document->title = $request->title;
$document->content = $request->content;
$document->category_id = $request->category;

$approve->approver_id = $request->approver;

$approve->save();
$document->save();      

$document->approves()->sync([$approve],false);
```

Honestly here I still don't have idea what should I put inside my `sync` array. It throws me a error `Illegal offset type`. Any help to correct my error?

**Update**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sync()` Method accepts the ids of the Models to be attached.

So, in your case `sync()` method will need `id` of the `approve` model.

```
$document->approves()->sync([$approve->id],false);
//assuming id is the PK for your Approve model
```

**Reference:** [Inserting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: oops sorry. I didn't notice that I comment out the instance of Approve model. I got an error. It doesn't get the current id of Approve model. `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webdev`.`approve_document`, CONSTRAINT `approve_document_approve_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`approve_id`) REFERENCES `approves` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `approve_document` (`document_id`) values (23))`

Comment: I think you are not getting ids, could you please confirm by `var_dump($document->id)` `var_dump($approve->id)`

Comment: Its getting the value of document and approves. The documents id is `33` and approves id is `28`. But it can't sync into pivot table of this id's

Comment: what is approves ? Is it a table ?

Comment: In your Document model's `approve()` method you have used Document model instead of Approve model

Comment: is it supposed to be that wy ?

Comment: Yes approves is a table. I tried the attach but it says `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::attach() must be of the type array, boolean given` I will update my post so you can see my diagram for a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120942/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-francisunoxx).